# How to find a degree 2 homogeneous linear recurrence relation given a formula

Tags: graph-theory, homogeneous-equation

Given the formula $a_n = (-1)^n + 2^{n+1}$, how do you find a degree 2 homogeneous linear recurrence relation?

Comment: $$T_{n+2}-[-1+2]T_{n+1}+(-1)\cdot 2\cdot T_n=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;\require{cancel} a_{n+1} + a_{n} = \bcancel{(-1)^{n+1}} + 2^{n+2} + \bcancel{(-1)^{n}} + 2^{n+1}=3 \cdot 2^{n+1} =3 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{3}(a_n+a_{n-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n-(-1)^n=2^{n+1}$$
so
$$a_{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1}=2^{n+2}=2a_n-2(-1)^n$$
Therefore
$$a_{n+1}-2a_n=-3(-1)^n$$
so
$$a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}=-3(-1)^{n+1}=-(a_{n+1}-2a_n)$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The characteristic equation of the sequence has two roots:  $-1$ and $2.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1}x + a_ny$. This gives
$$
(-1)^{n+2} + 2^{n+3} = ((-1)^{n+1} + 2^{n+2})x + ((-1)^n + 2^{n+1})y
$$
Separating this into two equations, one for the $-1$ term and one for the $2$ term, we get
$$
\cases{(-1)^{n+2} = (-1)^{n+1}x + (-1)^{n}y\\2^{n+3} = 2^{n+2}x + 2^{n+1}y}
$$
Dividing the first equation by $(-1)^n$ and the second by $2^{n+1}$, we get
$$
\cases{1 = -x+y\\4 = 2x + y}
$$
which may be solved for $x$ and $y$.